# How to access a multidimensional array by indexes given in another vector, when the dimension of the array changes dynamically?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, `Data`, and a `1xn` vector `Location` whose elements correspond to the indexes of a specific point I wish to access inside the array `Data`. 
Therefore, the number of elements in vector `Location` is always equal to the dimension of the multidimensional array `Data`. (`If length(Location) = n, then dim(Data)=n`).

So for example, if `Location = [4 0 9 3]`, then the point I am trying to access in `Data` would be: `result = Data(4,0,9,3)`.

If the dimension of `Data` would be fixed, I could simply do (if say, `n=4`):

```
result = Data(Location(1,1), Location(1,2), Location(1,3), Location(1,4));
```

However, in my problem, the dimension of `Data` (and therefore the length of `Location`) change.
This makes accessing `Data` more complicated and I'm a bit lost so as how to do this.

How can I determine the point in `Data` I am trying to access ?

If possible, I would prefer a solution that doesn't use any loops, but this might be impossible, so if you have a solution based on a loop, please propose it anyway!

Comment: Add sample input & expected output for such a multi-dimensional array case?

Comment: Doesn't `Data(Location)` work?

Comment: @BillBokeey 
It doesn't give me what I want because that returns a new vector whose element correspond to the element numbers in Data.
For example: Data [1 , 2 ; 3 , 4] and Location = [1 , 2]
Data(Location) returns: result = [1 , 3]
whereas what I want is Data(1,2)=2

Comment: Indeed. You need to do : `CellLoc=num2cell(Location);` - `out=Data(CellLoc{:});`

Comment: `CellLoc{:}` is equivalent to typing `CellLoc{1},CellLoc{2},...` which is exactly `Location(1),Location(2),...`

Comment: if possible try to use linear indexing. This will remove the dimension dependence.

Comment: @patrik linear indexing will be as problematic wouldn't it? I believe `sub2ind` doesn't work for vector indexes

Comment: @BillBokeey that is true and the reason why linear indexing would be preferred. The solution now requiring a cast to cell and a call `var{:}` to print every element as an expression. In case the vector `Location` would be set up of linear indexing instead, everything would be simple enough. Ultimately this is a design issue. However, this depends on what needs to be done. I know that `ind2sub` takes linear index and converts to subindex. At the point where this is needed the index is probably known anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `Location` a cell array, for the example given in the comment to your question:

```
Data = [1, 2; 3, 4];
Location = {1, 2};

Data(Location{:})
```

Which gives

```
ans = 2
```

**Edit as per comment by @BillBokeey:**

Either define `Location` as a cell array as above or use `num2cell` to convert the row vector `Location` to a cell array, for example:

```
Data = [1, 2; 3, 4];
Location = [1, 2];
Location_cell = num2cell(Location);

Data(Location_cell{:})
```

Comment: That's not really dynamic.. Please add a `num2cell` call on OP's `Location` vector

Comment: @BillBokeey apologies, I didn't see your comment before answering. Agreed, to convert the vector `Location` to a cell array use `num2cell`.

Comment: It's okay, just edit your answer with the `num2cell` call